# SSIS:Which logging mechanism is better SQl server or Text File

Tags: sql-server, ssis, bids, dataflow

SSIS has different logging mechanism. I am bit confused which logging mechanism should be used. Should I use SSIS log provider for text file or should I use SSIS log provider for SQL server. Which would give better performance? Or is there any better mechanism for logging?

Comment: It's difficult to run a query over a bunch of different text files. It's easy to run a query over a table. It's still not straightforward to get what you want out of of the SSIS log table but really there's no comparison. The only downside is if your logging SQL Server goes down you'll have some difficulties. The only reason you would use text files is if a non-database person had to maintain the system.

Answer (score 1):

Your question presumes that SSIS logging is an either/or proposition. You can use all of the different logging providers in the same package. Errors go to text file, warning and information goes to a table and start/stop times to yet another provider, that's totally fine.

The choice of a logging provider will likely factor into your organization's existing support structure. If you have a tool that centralizes Windows Event Log items, then you'd log there.

I've only ever logged to SQL Server as I'd much rather have a single, consolidated source for package history.

Comment: Agreed,when you look at simplicity SQL server is good approach.I was thinking in terms of performance... What would cause more I/O,SQL server logs or text File logs...

Answer (score 0):

When you add the log to a package, you choose the log provider and the location of the log. The log provider specifies the format for the log data: for example, a SQL Server database or text file.

Integration Services includes 4 to 5 log providers but i have mentioned following as you asked:

- The Text File log provider, which writes log entries to ASCII text files in a comma-separated value (CSV) format. The default file name extension for this provider is `.log`.
- The SQL Server Profiler log provider, which writes traces that you can view using SQL Server Profiler. The default file name extension for this provider is `.trc`.

**Note**

You cannot use the SQL Server Profiler log provider in a package that is running in **64-bit** mode.